Power Apps - Error When Trying to Retrieve Data From the Network
I'm trying to create my first Power App for a work project and am stuck trying to figure out this error message. The app is connected to an Excel file saved on SharePoint in which you enter a new entry, going through the form filling out all the fields. This seems to be working as intended.
The other aspect of the app should allow for a lookup of these entries and this is where my issue lies. By entering the correct matching values into three text boxes should always be enough to find a single matching entry with the code filtering the table to find it. The code and error message are below:
CODE
ClearCollect(
colEntries,
Filter(
Table1,
'Job Number:' = "SOAT00" & TextInputJob.Text,
'MO number:' = TextInputMO.Text,
'Build No:' = TextInputBuild.Text
)
);
Error Message
Error when trying to retrieve data from the network: ')' or operator expected at position 6 in (Job Number_x003a_eq ('SOAT006688"))and(MO number_x003a_eq '1'))and(Build
No_x003a_eq 1'). inner exception: )' or operator expected at position 6 in '(Job Number_x003a_eq ('SOAT006688))and(MO number_x003a_ eq '1'))and(Build No_x003a_ eq
*1'). clientRequestld: eb6ed149-928e-4feb-a9bc-dc8744e56a7c
Previously during testing I had this linked to the Excel file saved in my OneDrive Account and it seemed to work. I expected to change the data connection and for it to just need a quick adjustment to work.
With my limited code knowledge I've tried checking over the code to make sure all makes logical sense with correct brackets and semi-colons as well as ensuring all fields are correctly named and linked (Most parts are coloured to show they are linked, the only things that aren't coloured are the column names in the '')
